# How do I return a type that is unknown at compile time?

Tags: c#

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static object For<T>()
{
    var builderName = typeof(T).Name + "Builder";
    var type = Type.GetType(builderName);
    var builder = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    return builder;
}
```

And that doesn't error or anything, but the problem is when I call it:

```
var builder = Builder.For<MyModel>();
```

and then try to call methods on it:

```
builder.WithAnything()
```

It errors, because the return type of the method is just an object, rather than the type that was built within the method.

The purpose of this is to sort of have a factory that produces "Builders" (which follow the fluent builder pattern) -- and trying to create some syntactic sugar, so I don't have to do this:

```
(new MyModelBuilder())
  .WithParameter(2)
  .WithAnother(3)
  .Build();
```

At least, *I* Like the look of this much better (so this is the yet-to-be-achieved goal):

```
Builder.For<MyModel>()
  .WithParemeter(2)
  .WithAnother(3)
  .Build();
```

Can this be done in c#?

Comment: Maybe something with the [`dynamic` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)?

Comment: Seems to me the ratio of cost to value is not a good one for this.

Comment: Are the methods of all the builders the same methosd? So do all the builders support .`WithParameter()`/`WithAnother()`, or are there specific methods for specific builders, like `WithParameterOfFooBuilder()`/`WithParameterOfBarBuilder()`

Answer (score 2):

Servy has pointed out that you have left a comment on a now deleted answer where you say each builder can have different methods.

> I don't think this exact approach would work, as all the builders are
>   going to have different methods?

If that is the case, i.e. the individual builder types can have methods that you want to access, there is no value to the `Builder.For` method abstraction.

Put another way, if there is no single type that `For` can return that could conceivably be useful to you, except for the specific builder type you're trying to construct, you might as well new up an instance of the builder and be done with it.

If, on the other hand, you're interested in exposing a uniform API where arguments can be analyzed by the dynamically resolved builder to build the object, or in other words want to do something like this:

```
MyModel mm = Builder.For<MyModel>()
    .WithProperty(x => x.MyModelProp)
    .HavingValue(10)
    .Build();

MyOtherModel mom = Builder.For<MyOtherModel>()
    .WithProperty(x => x.MyOtherModelProp)
    .HavingValue("hello")
    .Build();
```

read on.

---

I'm speculating a bit here, but I'm assuming a TBuilder is supposed to have this sort of a relationship with T:

```
interface IBuilder<T>
{
    T Build();
}
```

Let's say you have:

```
class Tower 
{
    string Tallness { get { return "So tall"; } } 
}
class TowerBuilder : IBuilder<Tower> 
{
    Tower Build() { return new Tower(); }
}
```

You can implement the method like so:

```
static IBuilder<T> BuilderFor<T>()
{
    var builderName = typeof(T).Name + "Builder";
    var type = Type.GetType(builderName);
    var builder = (IBuilder<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    return builder;
}
```

Then do:

```
var tb = BuilderFor<Tower>();
var towerTallness = tb.Build().Tallness;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I think more information is needed though. Here is an example of the pattern I've implemented: http://stefanoricciardi.com/2010/04/14/a-fluent-builder-in-c/
So, I guess in order to use your technique, the lambda would have to specify both the parameter and the value? (meaning all the properties would need to be public (right now, mine are private))

Comment: You're correct about the relationship of the builder with T

Comment: I guess, alternatively, is there a way to use a lamba that all the attributes could be assigned at once? Kind of like ruby on rails's attribute assignment  http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/

But then still have compile time errors thrown in case refactoring needs to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Define a base class or interface for your builder types:

```
public interface IBuilder 
{
    // common methods and properties here
}
```

Make all your builders inherit from that interface or base class.

Then update your return type:

```
public static IBuilder For<T>()
{

}
```

Comment: You also got it wrong. T is not the builder but the model

Comment: I think he meant that return type should implement iBuilder interface i.e. `public static IBuilder For<T>();`

Comment: @flq Good catch.  the return type should be IBuilder, not T

Comment: This is unlikely to be useful.  The builder is going to need more than just a `Build` member; it's going to need methods for all of the different values to supply, none of which are going to be exposed when doing this.  These members aren't going to be common among all of the various builders.

Comment: @Servy If the builder is totally unknown at compile time, then you couldn't call a `.SpecializedMethodOfFooBuilder(5)`... The fact that you use a "special" method of a specific builder implies that you know of that builder.

Comment: @xanatos That's correct.  The answer to the question is, "it's not possible".  The answer provided here doesn't solve the requested problem, because that problem can't be solved.